# No response when using IBM MQ client jars in application to connect to IBM MQ server

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, message-queue, ibm-mq

The application I am working on needs to communicate to an IBM MQ server in a remote location. We currently have a working system using active MQ which uses a broker, and a bridge to connect to this remote IBM MQ server and is working fine.

Due to some new enhancement, we are now trying to achieve the same using IBM client jars instead of Active MQ.

The problem I am facing is that I can connect to the remote server's inboundQ and send messages.But I am always receiving null from the remote servers outbound Queue. But I have no way to check if the messages are received at the remote location.  But the same message if sending through the old ActiveMQ system will get a response from remote MQ server.

Old Active MQ internally uses the bridge to connect to remote IBM MQ server which is configured exactly like the new code I am using.

I have tried multiple codes from internet and stack overflow itself and always I am able to connect but not getting any responses.

Also, I get no errors or exceptions while trying to send or receive from remote IBM MQ.

I will paste a sample code which I am trying to get to work. I have changed some configuration values in the code.

My doubts are the following.

1. All I am doing for this is copying IBM MQ client jars into the application and using the code to send messages to remote MQ. I have not installed any other application. Will such a system work or should there always be some intermediate program like active MQ?
2. The same code is able to send and receive from an IBM MQ server which I installed in our local network but fails to get a response from the remote server? This leads me to believe if I am missing anything in configuration ? should anything else be configured other than in code?
3. I see no errors or exceptions. Always message is sent but the response is null. I have not seen the usage of any username-password or public-private key authentication. Is there any authentication used normally to check the source. ?
4. I am using IBM MQ client 5.3 version which I know is old. But used that since they working active MQ setup uses the same and is working correctly. I have no way of knowing which version on IBM MQ server is present on the remote machine. Is there a problem if we use a different client MQ version than the version of server MQ version. ?

Sample code which works for me in local environment ie is able to send and receive from an IBM MQ server I have installed in another machine in the local network. The same code will fetch null response when I am trying to use it with remote IBM MQ server.

```
import javax.jms.*;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import com.ibm.mq.jms.*;
import com.ibm.jms.JMSMessage;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;

public class SendReceive {
    private MQQueueConnectionFactory connectionFactory;
    private MQQueueConnection connection;

    private void runTest() {
        try {
            connect();
            connection.start();
            MQQueueSession session = (MQQueueSession) connection.createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            MQQueue queue = (MQQueue) session.createQueue("INBOUND_QUEUE");     /* values  replaced with correct values in deployment server */
            MQQueue queue2 = (MQQueue) session.createQueue("OUTBOUND_QUEUE");   /* values  replaced with correct values in deployment server */
            MQQueueSender sender = (MQQueueSender) session.createSender(queue);     

            MQQueueReceiver receiver = (MQQueueReceiver) session.createReceiver(queue2);

            //TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage("yesyesyes");
            String stt = "Test Message";        //

            TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage(stt);
            message.setJMSReplyTo(queue2);
            sender.send(message);
            System.out.println("Sent: " + message);

            Message msg1 = receiver.receive(5000);
            if(msg1!=null){
                String responseMsg = ((TextMessage) msg1).getText();
                System.out.println("Received: " + responseMsg);
            }else{
                System.out.println("Message received is null");
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Exception caught in program : " + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public boolean connect() {
        boolean connected = false;
        try {
            /* values below are replaced with correct values in deployment server */

            connectionFactory = new MQQueueConnectionFactory();            
            connectionFactory.setPort(1515);
            connectionFactory.setHostName("192.168.1.23"); // 
            connectionFactory.setQueueManager("QCCMGR");
            connectionFactory.setChannel("QCHANNEL");            
            connectionFactory.setTransportType(JMSC.MQJMS_TP_CLIENT_MQ_TCPIP);

            connection = (MQQueueConnection) connectionFactory.createQueueConnection();
            connected = true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            connected = false;
        }
        return connected;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SendReceive().runTest();
    }

}
```

Comment: @JoshMc The sample program is run on the same machine under same user with similar configurations. It nevers given an error or exception when i try to connect to send or receive. The remote system I am sending messages to is not owned by the company I am working for, so I have no way to check if they receive it or not. But remote server give response to messages send from activeMQ bridge which uses MQ5.3 jar. The reason I used 5.3 is only because the old working system was using the same. I intent to try the newer version, but somehow I feel I am missing some step or config here

Comment: @JoshMc Also the old activeMQ bridge setup uses two programs one to send and one to receive. If I send using the old acive MQ bridge setup I am sure the message reaches the remote. I have tried sending using old system and then tried to fetch response using my sample program. Then also I receive empty or null value as response .But if I run the old pgm for receiving after that , I will get the response to the message sent which means message was present in the remote queue but for some reason is not sent to my sample pgm. Why this happens I am not able to understand.

Comment: @JoshMc old system uses 5 seconds. I have tried with 10,15,30 seconds but still receive only null as response, so i do not think time out is an issue. I have tried commenting the code for sending part and running only receiving part of the program but again no error when connecting but response is null.

Comment: If you use the new system to send a message can you then retrieve that message using the old system?

Comment: @RobParker No If I send using new system , I am not receiving a response using old system.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to your problem?

Comment: @JoshMc  I have not received access to the system for last 3-4 weeks. The project is put on hold. Once I gain access again, I shall update the result.

Answer (score 2):

MQ v5.3 was released November 29th 2002 and has been out of support since September 28th 2007 (almost 9 years).  The version may not have anything to do with your issue but I would strongly suggest that you move to a supported version of the MQ client.  Newer MQ client versions can connect to older MQ queue managers.  You can download a java only install of MQ 8.0 or MQ 9.0 jar files at the links below:

- [IBM MQ v8.0 Client](http://www.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24037500)
- [IBM MQ v9.0 Client](http://www.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24042176)

---

I read on some old threads that having the sender and receiver on the same session caused problems when a timeout was specified.  Try adding another session for the receiver.

```
    private void runTest() {
        try {
            connect();
            connection.start();
            MQQueueSession session = (MQQueueSession) connection.createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            MQQueueSession session2 = (MQQueueSession) connection.createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            MQQueue queue = (MQQueue) session.createQueue("INBOUND_QUEUE");     /* values  replaced with correct values in deployment server */
            MQQueue queue2 = (MQQueue) session2.createQueue("OUTBOUND_QUEUE");  /* values  replaced with correct values in deployment server */
            MQQueueSender sender = (MQQueueSender) session.createSender(queue);     

            MQQueueReceiver receiver = (MQQueueReceiver) session2.createReceiver(queue2);

            //TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage("yesyesyes");
            String stt = "Test Message";        //

            TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage(stt);
            message.setJMSReplyTo(queue2);
            sender.send(message);
            System.out.println("Sent: " + message);

            Message msg1 = receiver.receive(5000);
            if(msg1!=null){
                String responseMsg = ((TextMessage) msg1).getText();
                System.out.println("Received: " + responseMsg);
            }else{
                System.out.println("Message received is null");
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Exception caught in program : " + e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

---

Try taking a JMS trace by adding the following to the execution of the java app:

```
-DMQJMS_TRACE_LEVEL=base
-DMQJMS_TRACE_DIR=/tracedirectory
```

ex: `java -DMQJMS_TRACE_LEVEL=base -DMQJMS_TRACE_DIR=/tracedirectory JavaApp`

This should produce a file that I believe ends in `.trc` in the directory you specify.

You can review this for errors that might help point you in the right direction.

---

Suggestions:

Try changing your program to force it to send a blank username:

```
connection = (MQQueueConnection) connectionFactory.createQueueConnection("", "");
```

Try closing the sender after `sender.send` is called

```
sender.close();
```

---

With out further information it is difficult to determine the cause.  The more information you can gather the better.

Comment: I have tried receiver only programs where session is used only for receiving, so do no think that is an issue. But will certainly give it a try.

Comment: I will get access to the deployment system now only after a week or so because or some other work going on there. I shall try to get a trace then. and I am sure no other app is connected receiving the response. if i send using old system and try receiving using new system, then no response but just after that if i try old system to receive , I will get the response. so remote queue had response but not sending to new system or for some reason getting lost in transit.

Comment: @Raj I think these two things provide a good indication that neither send or receive is working. 1. send from old system, and try to receive from new system, no response, start old system receiver and message is present. 2. send from new system, nothing is received by old system receiver.

Comment: I agree that neither sending or receiving is working. But it is the reason that fails me. All the connection parameters are correct and there is no error or exceptions . Also same message is send by old and new system. If i gv a wrong connection param like wrong inbound/outbound queue name then exception is thrown which means otherwise connection is successful. Why then the message is not delivered fails me. Also i have confirmed that there is not username/password etc for connection. Verification seems to be part of message itself which is same when send via old or new system.

Comment: Also sending receiving is working in development environment, when I am sending to IBM MQ server I installed in another system in my local network. This issue is in deployment server where old system works. Also the old system works in the dev environment I setup as well. At this point I am out of ideas but I shall try the trace when I get access to deployment server.

Answer (score 0):

It could be some network related configuration issue or maybe Windows Messaging  not configured well. You may consider giving [WebSphere MQ - Message Test Utility](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24007048) by IBM to ensure that there are no such *system or network configuration* issues are present.